# Filter sheet for values based on cell background color and copy these into a second sheet as row data

Tags: google-apps-script

w
Hello,

I am a teacher and I'm trying to improve a sheet i use for grading my students. I've put up a simple example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VhL6ontM7q1dN828YT_zrqeJz_eIShM6zpqnrnB9gBs/edit?usp=sharing), which contains none of the formula's or scripts of the original.

My example spreadsheet has two sheets (tabs). The first contains the student name and their corresponding test-result data per subject. The second sheet contains a list of names.

I am looking for a script to scan this sheet for cells with a specific background color. These cells are semi-randomly distributed throughout a couple of columns. The script should also turn these individual values into a set of row data, so it can be pasted onto the second sheet. The script scans the second sheet for the right name and pastes the values as a row of data.

What would be the way to go about this?

Thank you for your response,
Jof.

*edit:* code i have so far:

```
// function below is not yet selecting the right name to paste grade-values behind. First i need to get the filtering to work.

function collectGrades() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Desired-output');
  var allValues = sourceSheet.getRange(6,2,sourceSheet.getLastRow(),7);
  var allBackgroundColorValues = allValues.getBackgrounds();
  var Grades = findGrades(allValues, allBackgroundColorValues);

  targetSheet.getRange(3,2).setValues(Grades); //select cell B3 on sheet 2 and fill with the results 
}  

function findGrades(allValues, allBackgroundColorValues) {
  for(var i=0, iLen=allValues.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if(AllBackgroundColorValues[i] != '#ffffff') {
      return allValues[i];
    }
  }
}


// this function should:

// - scan the input sheet column B through H searching for relevant data by filtering for background color
// - collect this data into a single row of data
// - scan the output sheet column A for a match with input sheet B2
// - paste the data behind the right student name
```

Comment: I've voted to close your question.  A good question includes code showing the progress that you have made, and what you have tried so far.  Stack Overflow is not for stating what you want, and then have someone do the programming for you.  There are many, many people creating spreadsheets and code for use in schools.  Search for groups/forums that use Google products for schools.  You can also join the [Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769) Also [Link to Apps Script for Education](https://plus.google.com/communities/112780694700423616523)

Comment: You should go [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) look at getBackgrounds and getValues and using those two dimensional arrays you can accomplish what you need .  It's a little more trouble to reset the background colors.  You may find it easier to keep track of the ones you want to change by pushing them on to another array and then come back with setBackground.  Since your a teacher most likely your a good learner so you can probably accomplish on your own.

Comment: I've actually asked this question in a slightly different way before, with all the code included that i have used in my sheet, you can see it here: http://www.designboom.com/art/25-countries-photoshop-esther-honig-make-her-beautiful-06-26-2014/ 

The thing is, it is a confusing sheet to understand. I wanted to make this post as simple as possible, so i made an empty example sheet

Also, I want to getValues based on bg-color, net setValues.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of what you want the loop to look like.  It's a two dimensional array obtained from a two dimensional range. Height is sourceSheet.getLastRow() and the width is 7 columns. One of the oddities of Google Apps Script is that getValues always returns a two dimensional area even in those cases where its one column or 1 row.  You'll run into this problem again when come to performing setValues().

```
function collectGrades() 
{
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Desired-output');
  var allValues = sourceSheet.getRange(6,2,sourceSheet.getLastRow(),7);
  var allBackgroundColorValues = allValues.getBackgrounds();
  for(var rowidx=0; rowidx<allvalues.length; rowidx++) 
  {
    for(var colidx = 0; colidx < 7; colidx++)
    {
      if(allvalues[rowidx][colidx]!=='#ffffff')
      {
        //This is where you do whatever it is you do with non white backgrounds.
      }
    }
  }

}
```